# jquery token input not working in mozilla

Tags: php, jquery, yii

I am using yii to create a auto populate form.
I am using the token input jquery to find the required person.
The code that i have written is working in chrome but not in mozzila.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>

 <input type="text" id="bhi" name="blah2" />
 <script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#bhi").tokenInput("http://shell.loopj.com/tokeninput/tvshows.php", {
        theme: "facebook",
    });

});
</script>
```